# React how to check props before passing in another component

Tags: reactjs, redux

Lets say I have a component `<MyComponent check={this.props} />`. This will call `MyComponent` class. Here I am doing something like this:

```
render(){
    const {user} = this.props
    return (){
        <div>Welcome {user.name}</div>
        }
    }
```

In my container initially there is no `user.name` when the user is logged in then only `user.name` is available in props. In `componentWillMount` I have checked for `isLoggedIn` and if not I'm redirecting it, but in `render` method it checks for `user.name` property which is not available before login.

If `isLoggedIn` is true then `<MyComponent check={this.props} />` which calls my `MyComponent` should return a redirection or other.

Does anyone have any idea how to implement this?

Comment: have you tried `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` method?

Answer (score 1):

Your are able to check your props in `componentWillReceiveProps` method. It takes `nextProps` as a parameter.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
     this.state = {
       increment: 0
     }
     this.myClick = this.myClick.bind(this)
  }
  myClick(){
    this.setState({
      increment: this.state.increment + 1
    })
  }
  render(){
    return <div>
      <Child number={this.state.increment}/>
      <button onClick={this.myClick}>Click And Get Props</button>
    </div>
  } 
}

class Child extends React.Component {
   constructor(props){
     console.log(props)
     super(props)
     this.state = {
       count: props.number
     }
   }
   componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
     console.log(nextProps.number)
     if(nextProps.number % 2) this.setState({count: nextProps.number})
   }
   render(){
     return <div>
        <span>Props: {this.props.number}</span><br/>
        <span>State: {this.state.count}</span>
     </div>
   }
}

React.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

***[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/222/)***

Also please have a look at [*this*](http://busypeoples.github.io/post/react-component-lifecycle/) link i hope it will help you.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use check inside render method, in your case

```
componentWillMount(){
  this.state = {
   isLoggedIn: this.props.isLoggedIn 
  }
}
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
 this.setState({isLoggedIn: nextProps.isLoggedIn})
}
render(){
  return (
     this.props.isLoggedIn && <MyComponent check={this.props} />
    )
}
```